# How to add a new syntax feature for perl?

Tags: perl, syntax

I want to add a new feature for Perl language, in order to type less `$self->`.

For example, Translate:

```
use Moo;

has a_attr => (is=>'rw');

sub XXX {
   print $self->a_attr;
}
```

To:

```
use Moo;
use MyFeatureModule;

has a_attr => (is=>'rw');

sub XXX {
   print _a_attr;
}
```

How-to?

Comment: Here you go. Knock yourself out. http://www.cpan.org/src/

Comment: Modifying Perl itself is not necessarily required to extend the syntax - plenty of modules (like Acme::Bleach and Lingua::Romana::Perligata) are implemented as source filter modules.

Comment: @RaymondChen: I don't think hacking the Perl source code is necessary. There are Perl modules that modify the language syntax. An example: http://search.cpan.org/~dconway/Lingua-Romana-Perligata-0.50/lib/Lingua/Romana/Perligata.pm

Comment: @KeithThompson `Acme::Bleach` is what I work to

Comment: Perl is already syntactically complicated enough that it is often tantamount to write-only code (and I like Perl).  I am not convinced that what you're proposing would make your code clearer.

Comment: Apparently Perl has gotten more insane lately. http://search.cpan.org/~smueller/Filter-Simple-0.91/lib/Filter/Simple.pm Inventing your own syntax is a pretty good way to create unmaintainable code.

Comment: better idea, if you really are that intent on saving keystrokes: use `$s`

Comment: @RaymondChen, "lately"? Source filters are a decades-old technology and their use is fairly strongly discouraged these days. If you do need to extend Perl syntax, there are far better ways these days. Since Perl 5.14, Perl's C API has exposed hooks for writing your own keywords.

Comment: @tobyink I guess it slipped under my radar when it was introduced back in 5.8, which is a good thing because it would have made my head explode.

Answer (score 3):

This doesn't require any changes to Perl's *syntax*, only to its *semantics*. Luckily, that's not too hard.

What you want can be achieved by providing an `AUTOLOAD` sub for your package, which will kick in automatically whenever you call a sub that hasn't been defined yet (i.e. `_a_attr` in your example). This `AUTOLOAD` method can then use [Devel::Caller](https://metacpan.org/pod/Devel::Caller) to grab `$_[0]` (i.e. `$self`) from its caller, inject it onto `@_` and then `goto` the original method.

```
use v5.14;
use strictures;

package Foo {
    use Moo;

    has xyzzy => (is => 'ro', default => 42);

    sub sayit {
        say _xyzzy();
    }

    sub AUTOLOAD {
        require Devel::Caller;
        my ($invocant) = Devel::Caller::caller_args(1);
        unshift @_, $invocant;

        my ($method) = (our $AUTOLOAD =~ /::_(\w+)\z/)
            or die "Method not found!";
        my $coderef = $invocant->can($method)
            or die "Method not found!";

        goto $coderef;
    };
}

my $obj = Foo->new;
$obj->sayit;
```

Is this a good idea? Well, I certainly wouldn't do it. As well as introducing an unnecessary level of slow-down to your code, and breaking inheritance, it is likely to confuse anybody who has to maintain your code after you. (And that might be your future self if you take a break from the project, and come back to it in 6 months.)